# SMTPAuthenticationError 535

Tags: python, django

Я пишу сайт на Django. Мне нужно отправить форму на электронную почту.
Я столкнулся с проблемой:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /contact
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e14-20020a05651c038e00b0025a7056f4easm1107621ljp.85 - gsmtp')
```

Я использую mailgun для отправки письма
Website:
http://vedmenkoprod.ru/contact 
Source:
https://github.com/White-prince/Vedmenko.production 
The form:

```
   <form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <p><input class="inp" id="id_subject" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="100" required /></p>
       <p><input class="inp" type="text" name="sender" placeholder="E-mail" id="id_sender" required /></p>
       <p><input class="inp" name="message" id="id_message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="100" required /></p>
       <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

settings.py:

```
RECIPIENTS_EMAIL = ['myemail@gmail.com']
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '************'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py:

```
def get_contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['name']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, f'{message} от {sender}', DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, RECIPIENTS_EMAIL)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Error.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('contact')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('None.')
    return render(request, 'main/contacts.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   sender = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
   message = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Кто-то знает как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials . Скорее нет прав на доступ из приложений, популярная проблема

Comment: нужно добавить двухфакторную аутентификацию и создать пароль приложения. С помощью пароля приложения уже подключаться к почтовому ящику

Answer (score 0):

Согласно данным, которые предоставили Google:

> Чтобы защитить ваш аккаунт, начиная с 30 мая 2022 года Google больше не поддерживает сторонние приложения и устройства, которые предлагают войти в аккаунт Google только с помощью имени пользователя и пароля.

> Важно! Для клиентов Google Workspace и Google Cloud Identity дата прекращения поддержки будет другой. Мы объявим ее позже в блоге Workspace.

> Дополнительная информация приводится ниже.

То есть, разработчики больше не могут заходить в свои аккаунты только по логину и паролю. Теперь Google дает возможность реализовать только доверенным приложениям.

Остальная информация указана в [источнике Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=ru&visit_id=637921131602126585-4089621709&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1)!